# bigquery queryresults rows pagintation configuration options?

Tags: google-bigquery

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.21.1/bigquery/table?method=rows

Bigquery table has method "rows". rows() method can take parameter "options", which can be used for pagination

Such as

```
$options = [
            'maxResults' => 3,
            'startIndex' => 0
        ];
```

$rows = $table->rows($options);

Now what I want is using pagination in bigquery queryresults rows() method

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.21.1/bigquery/queryresults?method=rows

Here is the documentation for queryresults rows method. rows() also takes options as parameter. (But it does not give which field should be in the options).

```
$queryResults = $this->bigQuery->runQuery($query, ['useLegacySql' => false]);
$options = [
            'maxResults' => 3,
            'startIndex' => 0
        ];

$rows = $queryResults->rows($options);
```

But the options only ask for the top 3 records does not work. It still give me full set of queryresults rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems this is an issue on the client library (At least they need to improve the documentation). I suggest you to click "report an issue" on the queryresults documentation page and ask for clarification there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.25.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=runQuery

The maxResults option actually needs to be set on the runQuery call:

```
$queryResults = $this->bigQuery->runQuery($query, [
    'useLegacySql' => false,
    'maxResults' => 3
]);
```

Let me know if that does the trick for you.